# How can I schedule a method on demand call with timer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to schedule a method call when some conditions are met in my application for the user. The method must be called **once in 48 hours** after it has been scheduled. I have to be able to run this kind of scenario **unlimited** number of times. I tried to do this with Quartz.NET, but unfortunately it was not successful.

I would really appreciate some clarification and explanation on how this can be implemented. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also try to use Hangfire to call tasks by using code loops, refer to:https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html

Comment: I guess the majority of those who replied have misunderstood the word "*once*". The task should not fire every 48 hours after it being triggered. It should be fired one time only.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample but this may represent what you want.
This does create a timer that will fire between 0 and 48h the first time, and every 48h after the first being fired.
Each time the timer is fired, the method `Do` is launched.
For the sake of simplicity I've not included any object (null) for the method, but you could provide any input to the method, provided the object you put is still available when the method `Do` is fired, else the object will be null, or worse an error will happen.
I think Microsoft has provided multiple timer-like objects, and a new one exist on .NET5 or .NET6, can't remember.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

    class Time
    {
        private readonly Timer timer;
        Random random = new Random();

        public Time()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var due = random.Next(0, 48);
            timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Do), null, TimeSpan.FromHours(due), TimeSpan.FromHours(48)); 
        }

        private void Do(object o)
        {
            //what you want to do
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, but I also was wondering, if it is possible to add a job and a trigger to the Quartz scheduler, but without having them being actually "scheduled" to run, so that I could trigger the job later with the TriggerJob() method?

Comment: I don't know the Quartz scheduler. But the library seems powerful enough to cover all your scenarios. Take a [look](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html#trying-out-the-application-and-adding-jobs). 
You can define your job as being anything.
So you can store a list of job per user by example.
Then you can provide a default `ITrigger`, with a random 0h-48h delay.
But if you want you can just provide a `ITrigger` to start now.
Take some time to read the documentation and test on a separate application.

Comment: Not sure if timer-based or `await Task.Delay` will work if application restarts or being redeployded.